# Getting the Response code 401 message in twitter api request

Tags: android, twitter

The below code is getting response code 401.please help anyone to get search tweets from twitter api.I am using http urlconnection instead of httprequest.I need to get response tweets using jsonobject

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twitterlayout);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        twitter_consumer_key= "";
        twitter_consumer_secret="";
        oauth_token = "";
        oauth_token_secret = "";
        q="India";
        String get_or_post = "GET";
        // This is the signature method used for all Twitter API calls
        String oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        // generate any fairly random alphanumeric string as the "nonce". Nonce = Number used ONCE.
        String uuid_string = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        uuid_string = uuid_string.replaceAll("-", "");
        String oauth_nonce = uuid_string; // any relatively random alphanumeric string will work here
        // get the timestamp
        Calendar tempcal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long ts = tempcal.getTimeInMillis();// get current time in milliseconds
        String oauth_timestamp = (new Long(ts/1000)).toString(); // then divide by 1000 to get seconds
        // assemble the proper parameter string, which must be in alphabetical order, using your consumer key

        String parameter_string = "lang=en&oauth_consumer_key=" + twitter_consumer_key + "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method +
                "&oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_token) + "&oauth_version=1.0&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q) + "&result_type=mixed";`enter code here`
    enter code here

        Log.d("parameter_string=",parameter_string);
        twitter_endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json";
        twitter_url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=india";

        String signature_base_string = get_or_post + "&"+ URLEncoder.encode(twitter_endpoint) + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(parameter_string);
        String oauth_signature = "";
        try {
            oauth_signature = computeSignature(signature_base_string, twitter_consumer_secret + "&");
        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String authorization_header_string = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + twitter_consumer_key + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" + oauth_timestamp +
                "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + oauth_nonce + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature) + "\",oauth_token=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_token) + "\"";
        Log.d("Header String",authorization_header_string);

        URL url = null;       
        try
        {
            Log.d("Url",twitter_url);
            url = new URL(twitter_url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",authorization_header_string);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("Response Code :", String.valueOf(responseCode));
            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String responsedata = null;
            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(inputString);
            }

           JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(jsonCallbackToJson(builder.toString()));
            Log.d("Toplevel", builder.toString());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("URL-ERROR:",e.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException | JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("IO-ERROR:", e.toString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

401 means you have broke something with authentication

However, don't reinvent the wheel.

You can use [TwitterCore Kit](https://dev.twitter.com/node/1180/twittercore) that handle authentication and is easy to use tool for your needs. It provides a TwitterApiClient for making authenticated Twitter API requests.

Comment: Please tell me in which area i have mistaken